# How to check HTML file for occurence of two words in any row

Tags: html, shell

I have an `HTML` file in which content is like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Operaion1</td>
  <td>ERROR</td>
  <td>LOCATION</td>
  <td>OK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Operaion2</td>
  <td>ERROR</td>
  <td>LOCATION</td>
  <td>FAILURE</td>
</tr>
```

Now, i want to check this result.html file for occurence of ERROR and OK using shell script. For every row i have to check whether both ERROR and FAILURE exist or not for any operation. How can i do this? I am not able to form any command

Answer (score 0):

### Using lynx

```
$ lynx -dump result.html | grep 'ERROR.*FAILURE'
   Operaion2 ERROR LOCATION FAILURE
```

### Using awk

If you have an html-specific tool available, you should use it.  If you don't, we can get the answer using awk:

```
$ awk '/ERROR/ && /FAILURE/' RS='</tr>' result.html

<tr>
<td>Operaion2</td>
<td>ERROR</td>
<td>LOCATION</td>
<td>FAILURE</td>
```

#### How it works

Awk implicitly reads in one record at a time.  We will define a record so that it includes a complete row.

- `/ERROR/ && /FAILURE/`

  This is a logical condition.  If the current record includes text which matches the regex `ERROR` *and* it includes text that matches the regex `FAILURE`, then this condition is true.  Since we have specified no action, awk will perform the default action which is to print the record.
- `RS='</tr>'`

  This tells awk to use the string `</tr>` as the record separator.

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
$ sed -n '/<tr>/{:a;N;/<\/tr>/!ba};/ERROR.*FAILURE/p' result.html
<tr>
  <td>Operaion2</td>
  <td>ERROR</td>
  <td>LOCATION</td>
  <td>FAILURE</td>
</tr>
```

Appends all lines between `<tr>` and `</tr>` to the pattern space and output the block if `ERROR` then `FAILURE` is found.